# Use Selenium XPATH in Java to check element text

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

Here's the HTML where I'm working
[image]

My xpath locator and test look like this

```
    WebElement status = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='span4']/a[@class='status']/span"));
    String st = status.getText();
    assertEquals(st, "CLOSED");
```

Any suggestions for how to properly access the CLOSED text would be very helpful. My test is currently failing.

Edit: The String st is NULL. If I add an assertNotNull(st), it fails.

Comment: What does "failing" mean? Do you have a `null` value for `status` that causes `NullPointerException`? Or do you have a wrong value for `st`? In this case, what value? Edit the post and add the message that indicates the failure.

Comment: It is null, I added assertNotNull(st) and it failed

Comment: So, is `status` (not `st`) different than null?

Comment: It is not null, but I found out that there are other elements that are similar to the span I'm looking for, so my code seems to be grabbing the first one. I think I need to use .findElements to get them all and check them individually

Comment: If the other elements are not quite similar, you can add more restrictions in your XPath. E.g. `[@anotherAttribute='anotherValue']`

Comment: Okay, I'll try that as well. Thank you

Comment: You cannot get text if the element is invisible. You have to get attribute "innerText" of the element. `String st = status.getAttribute("innerText");`